# Cerrar eficientemente un JFrame en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas compañeros, les tengo una consulta. Alguien sabe como cerrar un JFrame y que al hacerlo libere la memoria que se utilizo en esa ventana? Pasa lo siguiente, tengo una aplicación en la cual me logueo y abre un JFrame que actúa como menú principal. Uno de los ítem de ese menú es otro JFrame, en el cuál se presenta un informe de todas las actividades económicasde los clientes. Lo tengo en un JTable y no en un IReport porque una vez solicitado esos datos, se cargan en un JTable y dichos datos son manipulados (ordenamiento, búsqueda del mayor, búsqueda del menor, agrupamiento según lo deseado en un momento determinado, etc.). Para cada registro de ese JTable yo puedo acceder al detalle de transacciones, para el cuál se me abre otro JFrame con esos datos. Es aquí el problema. Cada vez que abro las ventanas auxiliares va creciendo el uso de la memoria, y al cerrarlo esto ya no baja, se queda en ese máximo, limitándome la utilización de memoria.
Agradecería si alguien sabe otra forma de cerrar la ventana y liberar los recursos, ya que si cierro de esta manera `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, se me cierra toda la aplicación. Actualmente lo estoy cerrando con `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si evitas de tener referencias al JFrame el `GC` (garbage collect) se preocupa de eso para ti. Si lo quieres hacer más fácil para el `GC` de hacerlo para ti, evita referencias bidireccionales o usa `WeakReference` donde conviene.

La maquina virtual corre el `gc` cada vez en tanto, se nota cuando sacas un perfil de tu uso de memoria.
Si quieres comprobar si el `GC` **puede** limpiar tu `JFrame` despues del cierre, puedes llamar a `System.gc()` después del cierre y ver si algo cambia en el uso de memoria.

Si necesitas más datos sobre que esta pasando en tu maquina virtual, puedes usar por ejemplo [jvisualvm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html). En este enlace sobre [afinamiento de gc](https://notasdeit.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/afinamiento-de-garbage-collector-de-una-jvm-de-java/) encuentras más ayuda sobre el tema (que es un poco amplio).

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Te pongo un ejemplo: ComCheque llamar = new ComCheque();
     llamar.setVisible(true); ahí me abre el frame ComCheque y como debe ser el cierre para que los limpie el System.gc() ?

Comment: Despues del cierre tiennes que alocar `llamar=null;` Así no hay referencia al objeto y la vm lo puede limpiar en la proxima vuelta del GC. ¡Ojo! El `System.gc()`, es para pruebas. Normalmente no tienes que hacer, la vm tiene su lógica de manejarlo (lo que puedes ver si haces un profiling). Cuando creas y armas componentes trata de evitar que dos componentes tienen referencias el uno al otro y vice versa. Si un objeto no esta referenciado en ninguna parte, lo hace más facil para el gc de limpiarlos. Tambien puedes calibrar el gc cuando arrancas la vm, pero eso es un tema más amplio.

Comment: Hice todo lo que me recomendaste pero sigue manteniendo en memoria el frame y sus componentes ya que no baja el uso de la memoria. Es necesario coloque asigne null a todos los elementos del frame? entiéndase botones paneles y esas cosas?

Comment: No necesariamente, si un objeto padre no esta referenciado en ninguna parte, el gc puede limpiar todos los hijos. Más interesante es si algunos de los hijos (directamente o no) contienen referencias al objeto padre (por ejemplo agregado como listener). Te recomiendo hacer un profiling, te dejo un enlace en la respuesta.

Comment: Excelente. Muchísimas gracias por tu aporte Stefan